# How to open a messagedialog in a RAP application

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp, eclipse-rap

I'm trying to open a messagedialog in a RAP application by using this code

```
MessageDialog.openInformation(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell(), "Test","Testtitle");
```

My problem is, that I can't get a proper shell reference.
I'm new to rap and just edited the "hello world" example delivered by eclipse.
What steps do I have to do to get this to work?

Comment: What's wrong with `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell()`?

Comment: I'm note sure, when I use the to String function I just get an empty array, but the debugger shows an ID.
I also get an error saying "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.ui.testing.TestableObject" when my application crashes.
I did this steps:
1.) new plug-in project
2.) Template RAP Hello World
3.) Add org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.107.0.v20150825-2206.jar
4.) Execute MessageDialog.openInformation as stated in my post

Answer (score 0):

```
MessageDialog.openInformation(getSite().getShell(), "Message", 
                            "Message");
```

Comment: Please try to add some context to your answer.  While this may or may not be a valid answer, it doesn't provide an explanation as to how or why it solves the problem.  This makes it difficult for future readers to get any valuable information from your answer and relate it to their situation.